# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'FontStyle'

Tags: string, flutter, dart, fonts, flutter-hive

Im trying to store FontStyle Value and FontWeight Value in HIVE Database in Flutter as String Values.
However while fetching the values, im facing the issue of not being able to convert String value to FontStyle or FontWeight Value. I could use If statements and achieve it but is there a way to convert String "FontStyle.italic" to FontStyle.italic?

Comment: Is there an Integer equivalent to those classes? Example FontWeight.w900 = 1001239(Some Integer) ? @JoãoSoares

Comment: Is your issue just for FontStyle? Because there's only normal or italic. You could do a simple solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

`FontStyle` is of type `enum`, therefore you can't have an integer equivalence for it by default. However, since `FontStyle` have only 2 constant names `normal` and `italic`, then you can create your own integer equivalent. For example `normal` would be 0 and `italic` would be 1.

### Example:

```
// fontStyleInt is the int retreived from Hive (0 or 1)
int fontStyleInt;

// In the build
Text("Text", style: TextStyle(fontStyle: fontStyleInt == 0 ? FontStyle.normal : FontStyle.italic))
```